# Cant access the file because its being used in another process do I multi-thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, cryptography

I have this applcation where it makes it easier for me when I screenshot and I need to send the screenshot to a friend/family and I wanted to take it to the next level where I encrypt the image before it saves.

The issue is that when I try it this way, it cuts the stream because it says that its being used in another process.

Did I make it flow the wrong way? Do I need to multi-thread?
Which method would be best for this, Await & Async?

```
        public string generateKey()
        {
            DESCryptoServiceProvider desCrypto = (DESCryptoServiceProvider)DESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();
            return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key);
        }

        private void saveScreenshot()
        {
            string path;
            path = "%AppData%\\Image.png"; // collection of paths
            path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);

            if (Clipboard.ContainsImage() == true)
            {
                Image image = (Image)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
                image.Save(path, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }


        private void encryptImage()
        {
        try
        {

        string path;
            path = "%AppData%\\Image.png"; // collection of paths
            path = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(path);
          encrypt(path, path, key);

        }
catch(Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

}
    }


        //--------------------File Encryptor--------------------

        private void encrypt(string input, string output, string strhash)
        {
            FileStream inFs, outFs;
            CryptoStream cs;
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDC = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

            byte[] byteHash, byteTexto;

            inFs = new FileStream(input, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            outFs = new FileStream(output, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

            byteHash = md5.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strhash));
            byteTexto = File.ReadAllBytes(input);

            md5.Clear();

            TDC.Key = byteHash;
            TDC.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

            cs = new CryptoStream(outFs, TDC.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            int byteRead;
            long length, position = 0;
            length = inFs.Length;

            while (position < length)
            {
                byteRead = inFs.Read(byteTexto, 0, byteTexto.Length);
                position += byteRead;

                cs.Write(byteTexto, 0, byteRead);

            }

            inFs.Close();
            outFs.Close();

        }

        //--------------------File Encryptor--------------------


        private void screenshot()
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{PRTSC}");
        }
```

Comment: Identify your `IDisposable` instances and make sure you dispose of them in the shortest possible time-frame, preferably by means of a `using` statement. Hint: All `Stream` subclasses implement `IDisposable`

Comment: So I need to put the FileStream and CryptoStream in a Using statement?

Comment: Probably. I didn't look too hard at your question, but not closing (disposing) of a file stream frequently leads to "file in use" type errors.

Comment: Another thing: You are calling `encrypt(path, path, key);` -- your encryption method will (try to) open the same file twice, for reading and writing. That usually will not work.
Quick fix: make sure you are using two distinct files.
Better fix: Save to a stream instead of directly to a file. You can then optionally encrypt the stream before it even hits the disk.